# How can I obtain a new json with only unique values from the original

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm having a hard time trying to obtain a json that has only unique (date, hour) values from two keys combined. The json is something like this:

```
  {
    "date": "2019-07-11",
    "hour": "12:00",
    "idAppointmentsHour": 47914218,
    "shift": "T"
  },
```

So if they have the same `date` and the same `shift`, I want to group this info. Im using ES5, and my code so far is like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < agendaDatas.length; i++) {
    if (!datas.includes(agendaDatas[i].data)) {
        if (!datas.includes(agendaDatas[i].turno)) {
            datas.push({"date": agendaDatas[i].data});
            datas.push({"shift": agendaDatas[i].shift})
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried includes

All the values from the json are being copyied. i can't use ES6 Set because the platform runs in ES5.

Comment: do you have some more data and the wanted result?

Comment: Should "turno" above actually be "shift" from your sample data?

Comment: why do you use `includes`, but no `Set`?

Comment: And are you trying to group the results into groups of similar items or reduce each group to a single unique representative?  That is, should the output have the same number of results as the input, just arranged and categorized differently, or should we get a smaller set?

Comment: the expected result is this: {"date": "2019-07-11", "turno": [M, T] } or {"date": "2019-07-11", "turno": M}

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you could take an array of keys for a grouping identifier and use an object for grouping same groups.

```
function getKey(keys) {
    return function (object) {
        return keys.map(function (k) { return object[k]; }).join('|');
    };
}

var getKeyDateShift = getKey(['date', 'shift']),
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        var key = getKeyDateShift(o);
        if (!groups[key]) {
            result.push(groups[key] = { date: o.date, shift: o.shift, data: [] });
        }
        groups[key].data.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a cycle, on each iteration via `.filter()` check whether a match already exists. If not, then create it. Anyway, add the unique-ish values to the `group`:

```
//Test data
var items = [
  {
    "date": "2019-07-11",
    "hour": "12:00",
    "idAppointmentsHour": 47914218,
    "shift": "T"
  },  {
    "date": "2019-07-11",
    "hour": "12:01",
    "idAppointmentsHour": 47914219,
    "shift": "T"
  },  {
    "date": "2019-07-11",
    "hour": "12:02",
    "idAppointmentsHour": 47914220,
    "shift": "T"
  },  {
    "date": "2019-07-11",
    "hour": "12:03",
    "idAppointmentsHour": 47914218,
    "shift": "TY"
  },
];

//The logic
var output = [];
for (var item of items) {
    var existent = output.filter(function(current) {
        return ((item.date === current.date) && (item.shift === current.shift));
    });
    existent = (existent.length ? existent[0] : {date: item.date, shift: item.shift, group : []});
    if (!existent.group.length) output.push(existent);
    existent.group.push({
        idAppointmentsHour: item.idAppointmentsHour,
        hour: item.hour
    });
}
```

Comment: the expected result is this: {"date": "2019-07-11", "turno": [M, T] } or {"date": "2019-07-11", "turno": M}

Comment: @mresende so, if two different items have the same date and hour, then they should be a single object in the output, having a turno array where the shift values are stored?